# Implementing NSText delegate methods in PyObjc and Cocoa

Tags: python, cocoa, pyobjc

In the project that I'm building, I'd like to have a method called when I paste some text into a specific text field. I can't seem to get this to work, but here's what I've tried

I implimented a custom class (based on NSObject) to be a delegate for my textfield, then gave it the method: textDidChange:

```
class textFieldDelegate(NSObject):
    def textDidChange_(self, notification):
        NSLog("textdidchange")
```

I then instantiated an object of this class in interface builder, and set it to be the delegate of the NSTextField. This however, doesn't seem to do anything. However, when I build the example code from http://www.programmish.com/?p=30, everything seems to work perfectly fine. How do I impliment this delegate code so that it actually works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working for you is that `textDidChange_` isn't a delegate method. It's a method on the `NSTextField` that posts the notification of the change. If you have peek at the docs for `textDidChange`, you'll see that it mentions the actual name of the delegate method:

> This method causes the receiver’s delegate to receive a controlTextDidChange: message. See the NSControl class specification for more information on the text delegate method.

The delegate method is actually called `controlTextDidChange_` and is declared on the `NSTextField` superclass, `NSControl`.

Change your delegate method to:

```
def controlTextDidChange_(self, notification):
    NSLog("textdidchange")
```

and it should work for you.